# Selenium web driver in nodejs: no such element Error

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to locate the element using selenium web driver having name attribute on select element using the following statement but I got an error that "no such element"
`driver.findElement(By.name('TripType option:nth-child(ST)')).click()`
Then Select element where I am trying to locate that above id is

```
<select name="TripType" onchange="toggleT('divt1')">
    <option value="ST">Single Trip</option>
    <option value="AMT">Annual Multi Trip</option>
    <option value="LS">Long Stay</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why use raw webdriver for E2E instead of high-level solutions like Nightwatch or Testcafe, which provides much better error handling? See comparation here https://60devs.com/functional-testing-of-web-applications-using-testcafe-and-nightwatch.html

Comment: thanks for your reply @VladislavIhost. I checked the above by assigning the id to the select tag, it work fine but for name attribute above error is thrown. please help to resolve this error. thanks

Comment: You need to spend some time reading basic Selenium tutorials, blogs, other questions here on SO. You aren't using `By.name()` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try this -

```
   var value1 = element(by.tagname('option')).getAttribute('value');
   expect(value1).toEqual('ST');
```

If there are multiple options due to multiple options tag, then it can be modified to

```
 var values2 = element(by.name('TripType')).all(by.tagname('option')).getAttribute('value');
 expect(value2).toEqual([value1,value2,value3]);
```

Comment: I have replaced driver.findElement ... with your code var value1=.... But it now throwing an error that element is not defined.

Comment: My syntax is in Protractor. Sorry about that. Are you using WebDriverIO?

Comment: this is what i have required in my file var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'); I am using nodeJS. I am using that driver for some automation work.

Comment: I have just configured a little bit code using "chai" nodejs plugin and it returning the correct option value but now i want to execute  click as well. It throws an error "Click is undefined". Below is code 
`driver.findElement(By.name('TripType')).getAttribute('value').then(function(st){
 assert.equal(st,"ST").click();
 
 console.log(st)
 
});`